# Complex Numbers - Polar Form/Algebraic Form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having some problem with this question:
Write the following complex number's in the algebraic form:

$\dfrac{5i}{(1-2i)(1-i)(1+3i)}$

Comment: What's algebraic form?

Comment: I am brazilian so I truly don't know how to say it in english but it is like: -5+2*i for example... I translated literally from portugues to english :D

Comment: OK, maybe start by multiplying out the brackets in the denominator.  If you edit your question everyone can see how you get on.

Comment: Polar form! That's what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, that I understood correctly. Do you want to find $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{5i}{(1-2i)(1-i)(1+3i)}= a+bi$? If so, try following.

**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
\frac{5i}{(1-2i)(1-i)(1+3i)}&=
\frac{5i}{(1-2i)(1-i)(1+3i)}\cdot \frac{1}{1}=\\
&=\frac{5i}{(1-2i)(1-i)(1+3i)}\cdot \frac{(1+2i)(1+i)(1-3i)}{(1+2i)(1+i)(1-3i)}
\end{align*}

Remember $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{C}:(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the denominator out, then multiply the top and bottom with the complex conjugate of the simplified expression in the detonator, this will "remove"any is in the denominator. Just a reminder complex conjugate of a+ib is a-ib

Comment: A further reminder is "the answer must be in the form ( ) + [ ]i .